# How to solve the string indices must be integers problem in a for loop for capitalizing every word in a string

Tags: python, string, for-loop, typeerror, indices

I hope everyone is safe.

I am trying to go over a string and capitalize every first letter of the string. 
I know I can use .title() but

a) I want to figure out how to use capitalize or something else in this case - basics, and

b) The strings in the tests, have some words with (') which makes .title() confused and capitalize the letter after the (').

```
def to_jaden_case(string):
    appended_string = ''
    word = len(string.split())
    for word in string:
       new_word = string[word].capitalize()
       appended_string +=str(new_word)
    return appended_string
```

The problem is the interpreter gives me "TypeError: string indices must be integers" even tho I have an integer input in 'word'. Any help?

thanks!

Comment: how `word` is an integer? `for word in string` as per your code `word` is a single character in `string`

Comment: It's a variable and then I assigned it an integer with len(string.split()), no? Sorry, if I misunderstood the whole variable thing but new to cs.

Comment: Can we see some sample text and the expected result?

Comment: This is the result I got from the test:
"How Can Mirrors Be Real If Our Eyes Aren'T Real" should equal "How Can Mirrors Be Real If Our Eyes Aren't Real" when I used .title()

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are doing some strange things in the code.

First, you split the string just to count the number of words, but don't store it to manipulate the words after that.

Second, when iterating a string with a `for` `in`, what you get are the characters of the string, not the words.

I have made a small snippet to help you do what you desire:

```
def first_letter_of_word_upper(string, exclusions=["a", "the"]):
    words = string.split()
    for i, w in enumerate(words):
        if w not in exclusions:
            words[i] = w[0].upper() + w[1:]
    return " ".join(words)

test = first_letter_of_word_upper("miguel angelo santos bicudo")
test2 = first_letter_of_word_upper("doing a bunch of things", ["a", "of"])

print(test)
print(test2)
```

Notes:

- I assigned the value of the string splitting to a variable to use it in the loop
- As a bonus, I included a list to allow you exclude words that you don't want to capitalize.
- I use the original same array of split words to build the result... and then join based on that array. This a way to do it efficiently.
- Also, I show some useful Python tricks... first is enumerate(iterable) that returns tuples (i, j) where i is the positional index, and j is the value at that position. Second, I use `w[1:]` to get a substring of the current word that starts at character index 1 and goes all the way to the end of the string. Ah, and also the usage of optional parameters in the list of arguments of the function... really useful things to learn! If you didn't know them already. =)

Comment: This is the best solution without using any library. Thank you. I just started and I learned to code with C where I can store an integer of the length of the string this way, I didn't know it caused a logical error in python. Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 1):

```py
from re import findall

def capitalize_words(string):
    words = findall(r'\w+[\']*\w+', string)
    for word in words:
        string = string.replace(word, word.capitalize())
    return string
```

This just grabs all the words in the string, then replaces the words in the original string, the characters inside the [ ] will be included in the word aswell

Comment: This one works just like .title() did as it gave me this result for the test:
"How Can Mirrors Be Real If Our Eyes Aren'T Real" should equal "How Can Mirrors Be Real If Our Eyes Aren't Real"

Comment: I updated it so you can include ' and any other character you wish in the string, you put the characters inside the [ ]

Comment: Now after the edit, it did pass the test, thank you very much. However, can I use a variable to index a list? I am trying to code with only the basics without the use of libraries as I just started coding >.<

Comment: ahh, well what you did wrong was use word as the index, you want the loop to be for i in range(len(words)) with words being words=string.split(' ') then use i as the index

Comment: Oh so the index has to be one character so the interpreter doesn't see an actual string?

Comment: if you want to be even more error-proof, the regex r'(\w+[']*)*' will allow for words like y'all'd've but I don't think you want to be learning regex's as a beginner, but they are insanely useful when you learn them

Comment: No, the index has to be a number, words would be a list like ['hello', 'world'] so you go through that list word for word, no need to go through each character because you only need .capitalize()

Answer (score 1):

You are using string index to access another string `word` is a string you are accessing `word` using `string[word]` this causing the error.

```
def to_jaden_case(string):
   appended_string = ''
   for word in string.split():
       new_word = word.capitalize()
       appended_string += new_word
   return appended_string
```

Simple solution using `map()`

```
def to_jaden_case(string):
    return ' '.join(map(str.capitalize, string.split()))
```

Comment: I'm coming from using C, how can one index a list with a variable then? say the one used for the for loop..

Answer (score 1):

Look, in your code **word** is a character of string, it is not index, therefore you can't use string[word], you can correct this problem by modifying your loop or using **word** instead of **string[word]**

So your rectified code will be:

```
def to_jaden_case(string):
    appended_string = ''
    for word in range(len(string)): 
        new_word = string[word].capitalize()
        appended_string +=str(new_word)
    return appended_string
```

Here I Changed The Third Line *for word in string* with *for word in len(string)*, the counterpart give you index of each character and you can use them! 
Also I removed the *split* line, because it's unnecessary and you can do it on for loop like *len(string)*

Comment: So for something to be an index it has to be defined only in the index placeholder of the for loop, right?

Comment: I recommend you to read documentations and some sample programs, for most cases this problem won't be even considered a problem. And answering your question, the first parameter after **for** keyword, gives you a variable, which is an entity on list in next variable after keyword **in**, so in my case the thing range(len(string)) will give you list like [0,1,2,3.. length of string] and it will be substituted and used as variable word in each steps!!

Answer (score 1):

You have a logical error in your code:
You have used word = len(string.split()) which is of no use ,Also there is an issue in the for loop logic.

Try this below :

```
def to_jaden_case(string):
    appended_string = ''
    word_list = string.split()
    for i in range(len(word_list)):
        new_word = word_list[i].capitalize()
        appended_string += str(new_word) + " "
    return appended_string
```

Comment: Why is it when you used 'i' it didn't proper the TypeError and when I used word it did? sorry if its a silly question. Thanks a million!

Comment: for i in range(len(word_list)) iterates i as 0,1,2,3 ... upto its length but in your case word was a string and not an integer value

Answer (score 1):

In `for word in string:` word will iterate over the characters in `string`. What you want to do is something like this:

```
def to_jaden_case(string):
    appended_string = ''
    splitted_string = string.split()
    for word in splitted_string:
        new_word = word.capitalize()
        appended_string += new_word
    return appended_string
```

The output for `to_jaden_case("abc def ghi")` is now `"AbcDefGhi"`, this is [CammelCase](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Camel_case). I suppose you actually want this: `"Abc Def Ghi"`. To achieve that, you must do:

```
def to_jaden_case(string):
    appended_string = ''
    splitted_string = string.split()
    for word in splitted_string:
        new_word = word.capitalize()
        appended_string += new_word + " "
    return appended_string[:-1]  # removes the last space.
```